# How to cancel a SpriteKit Animation without leaving an (unwanted) remaining texture on the screen

Tags: ios, animation, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I've created this block of code to create an animation to make a selection visible. called in touchesBegan.

```
private func setSelectionAnim(atPoint point:CGPoint) {
    selectAnim.removeActionForKey(ANIM_SELECT)
    let action = SKAction.repeatActionForever( SKAction.animateWithTextures(WBTextures.Select(), timePerFrame: 0.33))
    selectAnim.position = point
    selectAnim.runAction(action, withKey: ANIM_SELECT)
}
```

`WBTextures.Select()` is an instance of a TexturePacker generated class and `selecAnim` is a `SKNode()` instantiated and added as a child to the GameScene in the init.

But if  I cancel the the animation (when a target is selected ) with the following code:

```
 private func stopSelectionAnim()
{
    selectAnim.removeActionForKey(ANIM_SELECT)
}
```

**The Problem is:** that when i call `stopSelectAnim()` the last presented texture stays visible on screen. which after searching the  SpriteKit Programming Guide

> Canceling Running Actions To cancel actions that a node is running,
>   call its removeAllActions method. All actions are removed from the
>   node immediately. If a removed action had a duration, ***any changes it
>   already made to the node remain intact***, but further changes are not
>   executed.

would be expected. After that a added the line `selectAnim.removeFromParent()` now the artifact disappears. But now the problem occurs that the next time `setSelectionAnim(atPoint point:CGPoint)` is called nothing happens. Logic if i deleted the node, but don't get a run time error ,so 'selectAnim' is not nil. Why does adding the extra line, solve the problem and introduces the next. 
 what is the best practice to interrupt an animation and still be able to enable it.

I've come up with a couple of ideas which none of I really like and fit into my scene setup.

1. re-instantiating and `addChild' the`selecAnim`in the beginning of each call to`setSelectionAnim(atPoint point:CGPoint)`
2. create an action sequence with a `runBlock()` which checks a Bool whether to stop and if so how do I stop the animation with in a block
3. adding the animation to a new `SKNode` and add this as a child to the `selecAnim` node. ( I've tried this one but the animation did not show at all see code: 
         selectAnim.removeActionForKey(ANIM_SELECT)
       let node = SKNode()
       let action = SKAction.repeatActionForever( SKAction.animateWithTextures(WBTextures.Select(), timePerFrame: 0.33))
       node.position = point
       node.runAction(action, withKey: ANIM_SELECT)
       selecAnim.addChild(node)

Do I miss the trivial solution or witch one is the best or do one of you please have a better solution.

Comment: trivial solution: when you cancel the animation, set a specific animation frame. You do so by assigning the desired texture to the sprite's texture property.